# shell script problem: does not work on the terminal, but works in a script

Tags: shell

I was playing with shell scripting, when a strange thing happened. I need someone to explain it.

I have a file 'infile', contents:

```
line one
line2
third line
last
```

a test script test.sh, contents:

```
read var1
echo $var1
```

i executed:

```
cat infile | ./test.sh
```

output was

```
line one
```

Then I did:

```
cat infile | read var1
echo $var1
```

Result: a blank line.

I even tried

```
cat infile | read var1; echo $var1;
```

same result.

why does this happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe causes the command after it to run in a subshell, which means that environment variables won't be propagated to the main shell. Use redirection or a herestring to get around this:

```
read var1 < infile
```

Answer (score 0):

Or try this:

```
cat file | ( read var1; echo $var1; )
```

Comment: It works because in your original example, the | starts a new subshell in which var1 is set, but the main shell (where the echo is) does not 'see' this variable. But in this example, the 'read' and the 'echo' run in the same shell, so 'var1' exists and is printed.